# Linux assembler error "impossible constraint in ‘asm’"

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm starting with assembler under Linux. I have saved the following code as testasm.c
and compiled it with: gcc testasm.c -otestasm
The compiler replies: "impossible constraint in ‘asm’".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int foo=10,bar=15;

    __asm__ __volatile__ ("addl %%ebx,%%eax"
        : "=eax"(foo) 
        : "eax"(foo), "ebx"(bar) 
        : "eax" 
    );

    printf("foo = %d", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?
(I've copied the example from [here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html#InlineASM).)

Debian Lenny, kernel 2.6.26-2-amd64
gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)

**Resolution**:
See the accepted answer - it seems the 'modified' clause is not supported any more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("addl %%ebx,%%eax" : "=a"(foo) : "a"(foo), "b"(bar));
```

seems to work.  I believe that the syntax for register constraints changed at some point, but it's not terribly well documented.  I find it easier to write raw assembly and avoid the hassle.

Comment: That works, thanks. Seems it doesn't like the 'modified' clause anymore, so I guess I'll have to push & popl whatever I change.

Comment: The modified clause still works; I think the problem is that "output" implicitly specifies "modified" as well, so having eax represented in both field was causing the issue.

Answer (score 7):

The constraints are *single* letters (possibly with extra decorations), and you can specify several alternatives (i.e., an inmediate operand or register is "ir"). So the constraint "eax" means constraints "e" (signed 32-bit integer constant), "a" (register eax), or "x" (any SSE register). That is a bit different that what OP meant... and *output* to an "e" clearly doesn't make any sense. Also, if some operand (in this case an input and an output) must be the same as another, you refer to it by a number constraint. There is no need to say eax will be clobbered, it is an output. You can refer to the arguments in the inline code by %0, %1, ..., no need to use explicit register names. So the correct version for the code as intended by OP would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int foo=10, bar=15;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "addl %2, %0"
        : "=a" (foo)
        : "0" (foo), "b" (bar)
    );

    printf("foo = %d", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

A better solution would be to allow %2 to be anything, and %0 a register (as x86 allows, but you'd have to check your machine manual):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int foo=10, bar=15;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "addl %2, %0"
        : "=r" (foo)
        : "0" (foo), "g" (bar)
    );

    printf("foo = %d", foo);

    return 0;
}
```